# Access form with individual record check boxes

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, ms-access-reports

I'm trying to have my access reports have check boxes that if you check one box in report view that one will be the only one that is checked. Currently if I add a check box in the design view and click it in the report view all of the check boxes in the report will add or remove a check mark, not just that individual box for that one record. I am unsure if there is a line in the property sheet that I am missing or that I'm missing something else completely.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a control source for the checkbox. You need to hold the value for each separate checkbox alone.
A checkbox without a control source (Under Data Tab in Properties) will show the same value for all records of the report record source (This is the same for forms).

For example, if you have a report showing Client Number and Client Name for all your clients, and you need to add a checkbox near each record, then the value for the checkbox should be bound to a control source from the report record source. So in the record source you should have the fields: client number, client name, and checkbox Value.

Comment: So to be clear I need my table where I'm getting my info for the report from to have a column with a checkbox? Is there a certain way to set it within the table? The control source portion/bound part of your comment I understand but i didn't get the results I wanted.

Comment: Yes, you need to add a checkbox from where you are getting your data. It is unclear to me why you need the checkbox, will it hold some kind of information belonging to the data, or do you need it for report actions like selecting a record or something else?